# .htaccess and url rewriting challenge

Tags: .htaccess, url, directory, url-rewriting, subdirectory

My problem is very simple.

I have several folders in my root:

```
[folder1]
[folder2]
[folder3]
```

And my domain is something like: **http://johndoe.net**

I keep my website in **[folder1]**, so basically I access it by typing **http://johndoe.net/folder1**

My goal is this:

I want to type **http://johndoe.net** and I get the content of **http://johndoe.net/folder1** but the address has to remain **http://johndoe.net**

I want to type **http://johndoe.net/folder1** and see my website, but my address has to change to **http://johndoe.net**

Seems easy enough, but I failed finding the solution after several hours of searching.

So far, the only thing I achieved is redirecting from **http://johndoe.net** to **http://johndoe.net/folder1** by placing this bit of code in my **.htaccess** in my root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^johndoe\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.johndoe\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/johndoe\.net\/folder1\/" [R=301,L]
```

When I type **http://johndoe.net**, I get **http://johndoe.net/folder1** in my address bar

but what I need is my address to remain **http://johndoe.net**

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to use two .htaccess files to solve this problem. Here's what you put in them, and where they go.

File #1. This goes in your base folder (the one that contains [folder1],[folder2], etc)

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www\.)?johndoe.net)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder1/$1 [L]
```

File #2. This goes in [folder1]

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

Comment: Thanks Holmes, you are a life saver, I spent like two hours looking for the answer!

Comment: I would point out that there is one part you requested which is not fulfilled by this answer:

If you go to http://johndoe.net/folder1, it will not redirect back to http://johndoe.net, not without further manipulation of the .htaccess that sits within the subfolder...*OR*...you have a website in that subfolder that handles redirection on its own.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter, your solution is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^johndoe\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.johndoe\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "\/folder1\/" [L]
```

you need internal rewrite, So it's enough to rewrite `/` to `/folder1/`